# Not able to open Edge Browser by Runtime.exec method

Tags: java

We are facing an issue where the below code is not able to open Microsoft Edge by running the command.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ProcessTest {

    private static final String NO_FRAME_MERGING_CMD_EDGE = "cmd.exe /c start microsoft-edge:";
    private static final Object DOUBLE_QUOTE = "\"";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String url = "http://google.com";
        url = new StringBuilder().append(DOUBLE_QUOTE).append(url).append(DOUBLE_QUOTE).toString();
        System.out.println(NO_FRAME_MERGING_CMD_EDGE+ url);
        Process process = rt.exec(NO_FRAME_MERGING_CMD_EDGE+ url);
        printErrorlog(process);

    }

    public static void printErrorlog(Process process) {
        try {
            if (process != null && isProcessTerminated(process)) {
                StringBuffer string_error = new StringBuffer();
                InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();
                if (errorStream != null) {
                    int c = 0;
                    while ((c = errorStream.read()) != -1) {
                        string_error.append((char) c);  
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
private static boolean isProcessTerminated (Process process) {
    try {
        process.exitValue();
    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException itse) {
        itse.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

In the logs we see

```
cmd.exe /c start microsoft-edge:"http://google.com"
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(Native Method)
    at ProcessTest1.isProcessTerminated(ProcessTest1.java:40)
    at ProcessTest1.printErrorlog(ProcessTest1.java:22)
    at ProcessTest1.main(ProcessTest1.java:16)
```

But the browser does not open.

When we run the command below in a bash file or on the command line, the windows is able to opening Edge. So I am not able to understand why it is not opening by Java.

```
cmd.exe /c start microsoft-edge:"http://google.com"
```

We are using jdk 6 to run the programm.

Comment: Try adding a `process.waitFor();` before `process.exitValue();`. You must wait for process to finish before checking the exit value.

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin You don’t need to call both methods.  `waitFor()` returns the exit code of the process.